# minimum k-vertex connected subgraph containing a given set of vertices of a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, connectivity

Let `G(V,E)` be an weighted, undirected, `K-connected` graph and let `N` be subset of `V`.
What is the best way to find the smallest connected subgraph `G'(V',E')` of `G(V,E)` such that `N` is a subset of `V'` and induced subgraph `G(V',E')` is `(K-1)-connected` ?

Comment: k=2 is probably about as hard as Steiner tree. I'd try integer programming.

Comment: Dear David, You are right for K=2 this problem is exaclty same as steiner tree. But I am not able to think how to approach  when K>2. Could you please suggest some standard algorithms to approach above stated problem.